# How can I see the details of an exception in Python's debugger?

Tags: python, debugging

Sometimes while I'm debugging an exception will be raised.

For example, consider this code:

```
def some_function():  # Pretend this function is in a library...
    # ...and deep within the library is an exception:
    raise Exception('An exception message with valuable information.')

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
try:
    some_function()  # Pretend I am debugging from this point using pdb.
except:
    pass
```

While debugging from the `some_function()` call, if I issue a `next` command I will see the following details about the exception that was raised [and caught]:

```
Exception: Exceptio...ation.',)
```

Here's a straight copy / paste from the terminal I was working in:

```
> /tmp/test.py(7)<module>()
-> some_function()  # Pretend I am debugging from this point using pdb.
(Pdb) next
Exception: Exceptio...ation.',)
> /tmp/test.py(7)<module>()
-> some_function()  # Pretend I am debugging from this point using pdb.
(Pdb)
```

It would be useful to see the entire exception message.  How can I do this in pdb?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Mine doesn't truncate like that.

Comment: Version 2.7.1.  Note that the raise statement is printed in it's entirety, so at first glance you might thing the whole exception is printed, but when the actual Exception is "intercepted" (I don't know the term) by pdb, it is truncated.

Comment: Well, I actually wrote my own variation of a Python debugger that doesn't do that, and also means to enter the debugger automatically (uses sys.excepthook). If you like you can try that instead. It's the [debugger](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdebugger) subpackage.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`pdb` stores the exception type and value in `__exception__`. You can print the exception part of a traceback in `pdb` with:

```
import traceback; print "".join(traceback.format_exception_only(*__exception__))
```

For example:

```
> /tmp/test.py(7)<module>()
-> some_function()  # Pretend I am debugging from this point using pdb.
(Pdb) next
Exception: Exceptio...ation.',)
> /tmp/test.py(7)<module>()
-> some_function()  # Pretend I am debugging from this point using pdb.
(Pdb) import traceback; print "".join(traceback.format_exception_only(*__exception__))
Exception: An exception message with valuable information.

(Pdb)
```

Unfortunately this does not include the rest of the traceback, but all that information is available through the `where` command of `pdb` anyway. If you really want the full traceback, you can add the following to your `~/.pdbrc` file or paste it into your terminal:

```
!global __currentframe, __stack; from inspect import currentframe as __currentframe, stack as __stack
!global __format_exception_only, __print_stack; from traceback import format_exception_only as __format_exception_only, print_stack as __print_stack
!global __Pdb; from pdb import Pdb as __Pdb

# find the last frame on the stack with an object named "pdb" or "self" that is a pdb.Pdb object
# works for pdb called the usual way, or pdb.pm(), or pdb.set_trace()
!global __pdb; __pdb = [__framerec[0].f_locals.get("pdb") or __framerec[0].f_locals.get("self") for __framerec in __stack() if (__framerec[0].f_locals.get("pdb") or __framerec[0].f_locals.get("self")).__class__ == __Pdb][-1]

alias traceback __print_stack(__pdb.stack[-1][0]); print "".join(__format_exception_only(*__exception__))
```

Then you can just use the new `traceback` alias to get what you want:

```
> /tmp/test.py(7)<module>()
-> some_function()  # Pretend I am debugging from this point using pdb.
(Pdb) next
Exception: Exceptio...ation.',)
> /tmp/test.py(7)<module>()
-> some_function()  # Pretend I am debugging from this point using pdb.
(Pdb) traceback
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    some_function()  # Pretend I am debugging from this point using pdb.
  File "test.py", line 3, in some_function
    raise Exception('An exception message with valuable information.')
Exception: An exception message with valuable information.

(Pdb)
```

Warning: all of this relies on undocumented `pdb` and `bdb` internals and is likely to break.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely useful hack. It's disappointing that there's no normal way to do something so common and so useful. This hack works also with pdb++ , so I'm switch to that over `ipdb`.

Comment: This technique doesn't work on Python 3 due to a SyntaxError.

Comment: Change the `print` statement to a `print()` function corrects the SyntaxError issue for any Python.

Comment: This technique doesn't work for revealing the traceback of an interactively-encountered exception as `__exception__` still doesn't exist if the exception was encountered interactively.

Answer (score 7):

The python debugger doesn't "break on exception" - which can be quite frustrating if you're used to that functionality.  As such, I adopt a policy of logging strack traces and working back from there.

```
import logging
try:
    raise Exception('An exception message with valuable information.')
except:
    logging.exception('Error in test code')
```

If you use a good IDE (such as Eclipse with pydev), the log entries for the stacktrace are made into hyperlinks that jump straight to the appropriate position in code.

You can dump a stack trace at any point in your code by importing traceback

```
import traceback
trace = traceback.format_exc()
```

Comment: It's better to use `logging.exception('Informative message')` which logs the exception traceback, and also any information about the operation which failed (the 'informative message', which can have arguments etc.). You can log at any level (e.g. DEBUG) using `logging.debug(..., exc_info=True)`.

Comment: I was not aware of that - thanks Vinay.  I'll update my answer if that's ok by you?

Comment: I'm using twisted.python.log.  I could use logging, but I'd rather not.  Furthermore, the try: raise; except: ... is not in my code but somewhere in twisted, (at least I think so).  So if I'm going to use logging like that I'll have to modify the twisted code.

Comment: The Python debugger does break on exception. Use `python -m pdb` followed by your script filename. What I usually do instead is run `python -i` or set the `PYTHONINSPECT` environment variable and then use `import pdb; pdb.pm()` upon an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import sys
sys.exc_info()
```

In VSCode, type the import in the bottom debug bar.