# Why does the python debugger in python 2.7 32-bits under windows abbreviate error messages?

Tags: python, windows, exception, interpreter, pdb

Sometimes the debugger abbreviates a run-time error message as shown below

```
(Pdb) n
> p:\hhu\updater4.py(136)make_and_execute_insert()
-> result = dbops.do( db.cursor, query.encode( 'utf-8' ) )
(Pdb) n
UnicodeDecodeError: UnicodeD...ge(128)')
> p:\hhu\updater4.py(136)make_and_execute_insert()
-> result = dbops.do( db.cursor, query.encode( 'utf-8' ) )
(Pdb)
```

When it does this I can't read the error message. Can somebody tell me how to stop this happening please?

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour. Are you sure that it is not pdb's fault?

Comment: That's probably the case. I have changed the title/description to ask the same question of the debgugger.

Comment: Perhaps it's down to Python's inability to display Unicode text on cmd.exe

Comment: In 2.7 shouldn't happen, [in 2.6 it did](http://bugs.python.org/issue15565). Eventually reopen the issue. For a workaround look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241200/how-can-i-see-the-details-of-an-exception-in-pythons-debugger